# Every time I try to run my app on the android studio emulator I get error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I'll copy and paste the message from the message gradle build.

```
Error:(14, 5) error: illegal start of expression

Error:(14, 12) error: illegal start of expression

Error:(14, 28) error: ';' expected

Error:(14, 35) error: ';' expected

Error:(18, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

```
Information:BUILD FAILED

Information:Total time: 15.311 secs

Information:6 errors 

Information:0 warnings

Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: check your code@Nobeel Gardenish

Comment: code please  ?    ?    ?

Comment: You're missing several semi-colons.  Your code isn't valid Java.  Fix the compilation errors to find out what runtime errors remain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a compilation error; the messages are clear.

Comment: I've looked for any wrong but I couldn't find it. Here is my Java code.                           public void onButtonTap(View v) {
        Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ouch!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        myToast.show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What IDE you use?
Re-check your code. There must be few lines with marked by red cross or similar. In error it says few semicolons are missing. You may probably forgot to put semicolons or it may be just caused from bracket/braces structure error. Just check the marked lines and few lines above and below.
 And if you put your code here, it might help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Clean or Rebuild the project. This error can be solved.